# C++ how to stop from crashing if entering letters

Tags: c++

I have a task to make a program that will calculate two numbers put into it.
And also show the calculation between every number.

[image: Console]

And if I input a letter not a number the program crashes, this is an more advanced task that I dont need to do but I really want to know how to do this. So that is my question, how do I make the program give me a warning that not to use letters and still give u ability to input numbers if you enter a letter, instead of crashing.

This is how my code looks so far

> Blockquote

```
float nmr1, nmr2;

cout << "Write two numbers.\n";

cin >> nmr1;
cin >> nmr2;
cout << "\n";


cout << nmr1 << " + " << nmr2 << " = " << nmr1 + nmr2 << endl;
cout << nmr1 << " - " << nmr2 << " = " << nmr1 - nmr2 << endl;
cout << nmr1 << " * " << nmr2 << " = " << nmr1 * nmr2 << endl;
cout << nmr1 << " / " << nmr2 << " = " << nmr1 / nmr2 << endl;



cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
```

maybe there are easier things to write but I'm a beginner, and I would use the search tool but I don't know what to search.

Comment: declare `string nmr1String` and `string nmr2String` and use them to get user input. then check if strings (`nmr1String` and `nmr2String`) are numbers, if so then cast them to `nmr1` and `nmr2` respectively. If not, print a warning.

Answer (score 2):

`cin >> var_of_type_float` will return `false` if the input fails.  So simply use that in a conditional expression, something like:

```
if (cin >> nmr1) { // all ok
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the input, usual way is to read a string, check if there are non valid character, then parse it into a number (tedious task in C++ with real numbers) and store in a float, finally, perform operations with those floats.

If you are not working with text input yet, I recommend you to wait to implement this feature, as it could be complex for a beginner in programming

Answer (score 0):

To check if a bad input was received via `cin` you use the following condition:

```
if(!cin){
   // bad input was received, don't use cin again.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What really crashes is the divide-by-zero operation.

If invalid number is entered, nmr1 and nmr2 will be 0

 and nmr1/nmr2 will crash. You must check for (nmr2 != 0) before attempting to divide.